# jquery sortable keep order on dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have these two lists where I can drop items from one to the other. 
The first list is the source of all the possible items. The second list is the list of items that the user chooses. 
On the second list, the order for the items is defined by the user, so my actual code works fine. I can drag on an item from the left wherever I want on the right.
The first list should keep a specific order. So if the user picks the third item from the left list, drops it on the right one and then **drops it back to the left list** it should return to the third position.

Actually the user can decide to put it back to any position. I haven't found in the documentation the possibility to keep a ul with a specific order, is this managed somehow?

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```css
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  table {
   font-size: 1em;
  }

  .ui-draggable, .ui-droppable {
   background-position: top;
  }
  
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  
  .ui-state-highlight { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable" style="border: 1px solid;">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1a</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2a</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3a</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4a</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5a</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable" style="border: 1px solid;">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1b</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2b</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3b</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4b</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5b</li>
</ul>
```

> Note that for simplicity this code is from the jQuery documentation (mine is a bit more complicated but this is the relevant part). That's why it is still referencing jQuery 1.*. 
>   Currently using jQuery 3 on my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to catch `update` event of the sortable.
I'd recommend you so save the original order

```
let originalOrder = {'first':1,'second':2,'third':3,'forth':4,'fifth':5};
```

and keep some kind of id in each item -

```
<li class="ui-state-default" data-value="first">Item 1b</li>
```

Also in case that we want to keep order just for one list, I'd separate this two sortable initializing -

```
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  update: keepOriginalOrder
}).disableSelection();

$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
}).disableSelection();
```

And the main func, that will do all the magic -

```
function keepOriginalOrder(e, ui) {
        var selector = $('#sortable1'),
    element = selector.children('li');
    element.sort(function(a,b) { return originalOrder[$(a).attr('data-value')] - originalOrder[$(b).attr('data-value')]; });
    element.detach().appendTo(selector);
}
```

I did not use just numbers as ids, just to show that you can use the original value as data-value. Just make sure that you set originalOrder with a correct numbers.

Try this out - https://jsfiddle.net/d1h8xvnj/